# how to run the iphone apps in the back ground

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement Daemon process for background task in iphone sdk 3.0 ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413154/how-to-implement-daemon-process-for-background-task-in-iphone-sdk-3-0)

hii every one

how to run the iphone apps in the back ground, can any buddy give me some example codes ,,

thanx in advance

Comment: For the record, this is the kind of question you'll get better and faster results googling than posting here. VOLUMES have been written about this and are out there ready for you to search for.

Answer (score 4):

You should have done some research before, but here you go:

- [iPhone app in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491381/iphone-app-in-the-background)
- [How to implement Daemon process for background task in iphone sdk 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413154/how-to-implement-daemon-process-for-background-task-in-iphone-sdk-3-0)
- [iPhone App - Generate Alert Popups when App is Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467313/iphone-app-generate-alert-popups-when-app-is-closed)
- [Is there any system level background queue process in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397846/is-there-any-system-level-background-queue-process-in-iphone)
- [push notification - background process - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381387/push-notification-background-process-iphone)

Reference [how to run my application in background in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547477/how-to-run-my-application-in-background-in-iphone/1548168#1548168)

---

Not to mention *iOS Application Programming Guide* [Executing Code in the Background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [official guide from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).